# Difference between Machine Learning and Computer Vision

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

What is the difference between Machine Learning and Computer Vision?
I am studying Machine learning now, for 1 week and still don't know what is different between them?

Comment: i found the kind of the answer above and get 700 up vote, why this question should be down vote. Please give me a reason @desertnaut

Comment: I already have, along with the relevant justification (links); please notice that the rules of SO have somewhat changed during its 10-year history, and questions that might be on-topic 7-8 years ago can very well be off-topic *today*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you prefer axe to cut an apple? even a simple knife is enough for it!
Will you prefer sword to sew a pyjama? a short needle is enough for it!
Same is the case of comments made above. 
Computer vision do deals with image recognition too, but you don't need it for simple face recognition project. It is a basic project of machine learning and is available on many GitHub kind of websites for free. So, you don't need to learn "computer vision" especially to build a face recognition system. 
Computer vision is a good field, but machine learning is sufficient for face recognition!

Comment: nice answer, but when should i use Computer Vision?

Comment: We use computer vision when we have to emulate Human Vision for example automatic defect detection, Self-driving cars, delivery systems using drones, etc.

Comment: Your mixing between image processing and Vision - Vision is a field in computer science that contains algorithms for understanding vision and most of the algorithm we are working with are machine learning / deep based

Comment: It’s a ridiculous answer, “you don’t need to learn computer vision to build a face recognition system” it’s simply wrong , if you build a face recognition model you are doing Vision.. and  you can and probably will use ML for doing it..

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking computer vision is a field that uses some machine learning techniques to solve problems related to the field, that is, making a computer recognize images and identify what's in them!

Comment: i want to make face recognition is it mean i should learn computer vision too ?

Comment: Yes, I recommend you to look at the most common techniques used for face recognition

Answer (score -1):

### Machine learning:

Machine learning is the science of making computers learn and act like humans by feeding data and information without being explicitly programmed.

### Example:

When we coming to the computer, Writing a peace of code or program and telling the computer step by step to do. But ML we don't do that, the system learns on its own. We just provide the past data(called labelled data) and the system learns during the process what is known as training process, we tell the system the system the outcome are right or wrong, that feedback is taken by system and it corrects itself and that's who its learns, it gives the correct output of the most of the cases. Obviously it is not 100% correct but aim is to get as accurate as possible.

### Computer vision:

Computer vision is nothing but dealing with the digital images and videos in the computer. Computer vision is evolving rapidly day-by-day. Its one of the reason is deep learning. When we talk about computer vision, a term convolutional neural network( abbreviated as CNN) comes in our mind because CNN is heavily used here. Examples of CNN in computer vision are face recognition, image classification etc. It is similar to the basic neural network. CNN also have learn able parameter like neural network i.e, weights, biases etc.